# Find parent module commit when going to past commit in submodule and brach in parent module was not created

Tags: git

If you are working in a Repo hierarchy of 3 module repository. This is the main repo, and 2 hierachies of submodules.

```
MainRepo
    Submodule1
        Submodule2
```

You work happily in your branch that you make in submodule1, lets call it `sbm1Branch`, and the team is updating the proyect in the MainRepo. Suddently you realized you did not make the branch in the parent repo, so you do pull in the main repo, and make your branch from there(because you take the chance to merge the development teams branch in yours to be updated and solve the conflicts). 
Then you realize that you need to go back some commits to check something in that specific commit project status. 
¿How do you know the parent MainRepo commit you are supposed to be in for the commit of your branch sbm1Branch you need to provisionally go back to?? 
(this could be needed to solve compilation errors because in the MainRepo now you are updated, so many commits ahead from the "parallel" commit of the sbm1Branch you were in when you pushed that commit, but the branch in the parent repo with the brach in the parent was not made yet).

If this is not possible, guess that the good practice is to make always the corresponding branches updating the pointers up to the parent module, because if that is not done, even you can go back some commits in your submodule branch, you might not be able to retrieve the status of the whole project for that specific commit you may want to go back to, because you dont know the equivalent commit of the parent module.

Hope I made myself understood. Thanks

EDIT: There is a kind of workaround. If there were previous merges of the branch your team works in, lets call it `develop`, which is my case, you can check the last commit where you las merged `develop` into your working branch `sbm1Branch`. There you should have presumably pulled from the parent repo and updated the whole project status in all the repos, so back in that commit you should be fine. Now the question is if there is a more sophisticated way to find this commit for this particular scenario.